# MS Teams Vue integration

Tags: vue.js, microsoft-teams

Is there any good documentation for integrating Vue js for MS Teams app development? I couldnt find any good resources.

Are the tabs in MS Teams app self updating? Do they update with new data in tab or do users have to manually refresh the tab?

Comment: To integrate Vue.js for MS Teams app development, you can refer to the Fluent UI documentation. Here is the link to the Fluent UI documentation: [Fluent UI documentation](https://react.fluentui.dev/?path=/docs/concepts-introduction--page). 
Regarding the tabs in MS Teams app, they can be self-updating. You can update the tab dynamically without requiring users to manually refresh the tab using the [Teams JavaScript SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/msteams-client?view=msteams-client-js-latest&tabs=npm).

Comment: You can also refer to this [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Client-side_JavaScript_frameworks/Vue_getting_started) and [this blog](https://sibeeshpassion.com/create-microsoft-teams-app-using-vuejs-azure-javascript-sdk/) which explains how to integrate Vue js for MS Teams app development